# How to initialize an array that is a member of a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

For example I have a class called DeckOfCards and array char *suit[ 4 ].

```
class DeckOfCards
{
public:
    // some stuff

private:
    char *suit[ 4 ];
};
```

Where I can initialize this array in such a way? `char *suit[ 4 ] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" }` I guess it can be done using constructor, but I don't know how exactly to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You could create it as a static variable in the class, like this:

```
class DeckOfCards
{
public:
  DeckOfCards() {
    printf("%s\n", suit[0]);
  }

private:
  static const char *suit[];
};

const char *DeckOfCards::suit[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };

int main(void)
{
  DeckOfCards deck;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't create it as a static variable because in some functions of this class I copy elements from `suit` array to another array.

Comment: I don't understand what having a static array has to do with the inability to copy values later on.

Comment: sorry, I confused something. I'll try to create it as static variable.

Comment: Anyway, I just tried to copy an element from `const char suit*` to another `char*` (non-constant) array like this: `dealedSuits[ dealedFcounter ] = suit[ row ];` and MSVC++ shows me an error that value of type `const char*` cannot be assigned to `char*`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards()
    :suit{ "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" }
{}
```

If that doesn't work, then your compiler doesn't support that feature of C++ yet.  So you'll need to do it the old fashion way:

```
DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards()    
{
    suit[0] = "Hearts";
    suit[1] = "Diamonds";
    suit[2] = "Clubs";
    suit[3] = "Spades";
}
```

If you're going to use char pointers like that though, you should make them const, i.e.:

```
const char *suit[ 4 ];
```

Reason being, you can't modify the strings anyway, string literals reside in read-only memory.  By declaring it const, at least the compiler will tell you your problem if you try to modify it.  Better to avoid all that and just use `std::string`.